# macOS get GPU history (usage) from terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, gpu

In recent versions of Activity Monitor, one can press CMD+4 and get a graphical representation of GPU usage. However, I want to obtain this info from my native macOS app and therefore I'm searching for a way to get this data (shown in Activity Monitor) from macOS command line.

[image: Activity Monitor GPU History Info on macOS]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can obtain information about the GPU usage using the built-in `powermetrics` command e.g to obtain one snapshot (`-n1`) over 0.5 sec (`-i500` ms) of the GPU info (`--samplers gpu_power`):

```
sudo powermetrics --samplers gpu_power -i500 -n1
```

Note: You can check which `samplers` powermetrics supports by typing:

```
powermetrics -h
```

Comment: This gives a very different perception of usage compared to the ambiguous display of Activity Monitor (just some stark relative graph with no units.)  If one assumes the vertical percentage graphed in the window is relative to the height of the window, Activity Monitor gives the impression of a much lower usage - about 1/3 of what powermetrics GPU Busy is reporting on my machines.